# Working/Include Direct of a Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, velocity

I'm currently starting to learn to use java to create dynamic websites.
I've started using a servlet and the template engine 'velocity'.

My Environement:

```
WebContent/
   WEB-INF/
      gallery/
         template.file
```

My Question: I want to use the "template.file" as template. WHAT filename/path do I have to enter to reach my template from a servlet.

Sorry for my bad english :/ It's currently very hot in germany.

Best regards,
andre

EDIT: Some Code...

```
/* Create and setup the Template system */
template = new VelocityEngine();
template.init();
template.getTemplate("template.file"); <--- Waht directory to use
```

Comment: Please show us your servlet code that needs a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `WEB-INF/` is on the classpath, you cannot load templates without reconfiguring Velocity. Velocity uses a file-based approach by default. You need to tell Velocity to look on the classpath of the web application, which then uses the *ServletContext* to load resources packaged within the web application archive.

Please see the [Velocity documentation about loading resources in web applications](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/webapps.html) for a detailed description on how to configure Velocity to load templates from within a web application.